# Automatically convert a file whenever it is saved?

Tags: applescript, automator, folder-action

Is it possible to automatically convert a file to another format every time it is saved?

Some context:  I have a Numbers file which needs to be converted to csv for processing by various shell scripts.  At the moment I have to manually "Export to CSV" each time I edit the file, which I don't always remember.

The ideal solution would be to automatically trigger the "Export.." action every time the file is saved.  Is there any way to do this?  I would prefer a folder action, because I have a few different Numbers files with same problem.

Just to be clear:  the problem is how to *trigger* the conversion.

I'm using Numbers 3.2.2 on Mac OS X 10.9.5

Answer (score 1):

Yes, OS X has built in automation with Applescript and folder actions.

- http://www.macworld.com/article/1167157/automate_tasks_with_folder_actions.html
- http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/folder-actions-tutorial-automation-meet-the-filesystem/
- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_folder_actions.html
- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/index.html
- http://macosxautomation.com

So, following the first link from MacWorld you can make a folder on your desktop that pops up an alert when you save your file. From there, you would make a different folder with a different script to attempt to convert the file. Lastly, make a script to clean up the file that's converted and move the processed file to the proper place.

I would instead make a service to just convert the file in place, but you can't trigger a service as easily as you can trigger a folder based workflow where actions initiate the processing.

Comment: I am aware that Applescript and folder actions exist.  The question is how to trigger an action when an existing file is saved.  None of the links you posted answers this question, nor even indicates whether a solution to the specific question I asked is possible.

Comment: The action is triggered when the file enters the folder. Have the script move the file to the actual place at the end of the action and/or prompt the user for a new destination if desired. Folder Action => the script runs when you save a file. It requires rethinking your workflow or using a tool like Hazel to automate placement of the processed save files once you've moved them out of the folder that does the CSV processing... Do you get the alert that my first link shows for turning on the actions when you save your file?

Comment: This comment is a little too compressed for me to follow.  Maybe you could expand it into an full answer?  Assume that I have an Applescript that does what I want.  What do I have to do to ensure that it gets called when I press "Save" in Numbers?

Comment: The alert example you pointed to gives an alert when a new file is created, not when an existing file is edited.

Comment: Yes - make a new file in the folder and then move it. That's how to program/automate, break the problem down into little chunks and then assemble one chunk after the other. :-)

Comment: This would totally defeat the point.  Did you read the question?  You are wasting both our time.